# Which statistical test to use for 3-choice bioassay?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I have a bioassay containing 3 different treatments. A single individual is allowed to choose between the 3 choices and their choice is recorded. This test is perform 30 times, each with a different individual. My data consists of the number of individuals that chose each treatment (so 3 numbers). Which statistical test is suitable for this data?

Comment: What is your hypothesis?  Are you, for example, interested in showing the proportion of subjects choosing between the three is different than 1/3?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if the there is a difference in the preference of the subjects to each treatment. Ideally I would also like to determine if a particular treatment had a significantly higher number of individuals choosing it compared to another as well.

Comment: use a chi-square test to determine if the frequencies of choices are different from uniformly random.  Because there are just 3, run all pairwise comparisons and use something like a Bonferonni correction (or don't, the inflation to the type 1 error is going to be minimal)

Comment: Thanks Demetri!